# How do I truncate or clear a file that's in use?

Tags: windows, windows-2000

We have a Windows 2000 box running Apache that's running out of disk space. We can't shut down or restart Apache to clear the lock (I'm a UNIX guy, not sure what the equivelant term for Windows is) on the file because it takes too long to restart.

Trying something like

```
ren access_log access_log.bak
```

or

```
del access_log
```

results in

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

How do we clear down the file without taking down Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache is currently using that file, the only real way is to kill the process that the file is being used by, Apache.

You can try using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) on the file and see if you can remove the lock, it could help.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think this will work for Windows 2000 (quick google says PowerShell for Win 2000 is not supported) but I found this forum post that works for me on Win 7, figured I'd share it here for others looking to do the same:

http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1538826

Basically, get yourself a copy of [Windows PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/powershell) and run this command:

```
while ($true) { gci c:\some\dir -recurse -Include mylogfile.log | ? { $_.length -gt 100mb } | Clear-Content; sleep 15 }
```

This will truncate the log file every time it grows above 100MB for as long as you let the command run.